# Empty result in user_recyclebin table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE t_test (id VARCHAR2(255), name VARCHAR2(255));
DROP TABLE t_test;
```

When I look the `user_recyclebin` table by following query,

```
SELECT * FROM user_recyclebin;
```

There is no rows selected and I can't flashback the `t_test` table. Please explain me. Why?

Comment: What's the output of `show parameters recyclebin` in SQL*Plus?

Comment: NAME is "recyclebin", TYPE is "string" and VALUE is "on".

Comment: Does your schema match your user; it could be changed by a logon trigger, maybe? Do you get the same values from `select user, sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') from dual;`?

Comment: Both values of user and sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') is "SYSTEM".

Comment: You should not be creating objects in the `SYSTEM` schema. Create a new user and create your objects under that.

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmflash.htm#sthref1590):

> The recycle bin is only available for non-system, locally managed tablespaces.

You are doing this as `SYSTEM`, which is a really bad idea for a lot of reasons. In this case the default tablespace for `SYSTEM` is `SYSTEM`, which may be locally managed but fails the 'non-system' requirement.

But really [don't create your own objects as `SYSTEM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dba005.htm#ADMIN11044):

> The SYSTEM user name is used to create additional tables and views
>   that display administrative information, and internal tables and views
>   used by various Oracle Database options and tools. Never use the
>   SYSTEM schema to store tables of interest to non-administrative users.

Don't use [`SYS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dba005.htm#ADMIN11043) either, or any default accounts. Create your own user and create objects under that schema.

Comment: Can I do this by new user with DBA Role?

Comment: I do like that **GRANT DBA TO username**. But it is not working yet.

Comment: @PyaeThuAung - you should not grant DBA unless you really need to; you should grant the minimum privileges to the user to let them perform their activities; and you should probably grant those via a role to make managing them easier. That's too long a discussion for comments though. Maybe start with [the security guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/users.htm).

Comment: Anybody who doesn't know why it's a bad idea to create objects in the SYSTEM tablespace should be allowed to connect to a real database as a DBA.  But provided it's a toy database and nobody else cares, go ahead.